# Stream Web Depth Camera (Intel D455) with python

Tags: python, web, stream, camera, depth

I'm trying to stream the depth and RGB video of a depth camera (Intel D455) through web.

I'm re-using a script from here: https://pyshine.com/Live-streaming-multiple-videos-on-a-webpage/

My probleme is the following, when I start the script and the 2 threads, the 2 ports (9000 and 9001 will display the last thread) but if I only start one of them, the good port display the good video (and of course the other doesn't work...

Do you have an idea where I've made a mistake? (Maybe in the pipeline?)

Thanks

Here is the code:

> 

```
import cv2
import  pyshine as ps 
from multiprocessing import Process
import pyrealsense2 as rs
import numpy as np
import threading

HTML="""
<html>
<head>
<title>PyShine Live Streaming</title>
</head>

<body>
<center><h1> PyShine Live Streaming Multiple videos </h1></center>
<center><img src="10.112.33.161:9000/stream.mjpg" width='360' height='240' autoplay playsinline></center>

</body>
</html>
"""



# Configure depth and color streams
pipeline = rs.pipeline()
config = rs.config()

# Get device product line for setting a supporting resolution
pipeline_wrapper = rs.pipeline_wrapper(pipeline)
pipeline_profile = config.resolve(pipeline_wrapper)
device = pipeline_profile.get_device()
device_product_line = str(device.get_info(rs.camera_info.product_line))

found_rgb = False
for s in device.sensors:
    if s.get_info(rs.camera_info.name) == 'RGB Camera':
        found_rgb = True
        break
if not found_rgb:
    print("The demo requires Depth camera with Color sensor")
    exit(0)

config.enable_stream(rs.stream.depth, 640, 480, rs.format.z16, 30)

if device_product_line == 'L500':
    config.enable_stream(rs.stream.color, 960, 540, rs.format.bgr8, 30)
else:
    config.enable_stream(rs.stream.color, 640, 480, rs.format.bgr8, 30)





class ImgCapture():

    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def read(self):
        # Wait for a coherent pair of frames: depth and color
        self.frames = pipeline.wait_for_frames()
        depth_frame = self.frames.get_depth_frame()
        color_frame = self.frames.get_color_frame()

        # Convert images to numpy arrays
        depth_image = np.asanyarray(depth_frame.get_data())
        color_image = np.asanyarray(color_frame.get_data())

        # Apply colormap on depth image (image must be converted to 8-bit per pixel first)
        depth_colormap = cv2.applyColorMap(cv2.convertScaleAbs(depth_image, alpha=0.03), cv2.COLORMAP_BONE)
        depth_colormap_dim = depth_colormap.shape
        color_colormap_dim = color_image.shape

        # If depth and color resolutions are different, resize color image to match depth image for display
        if depth_colormap_dim != color_colormap_dim:
            color_image = cv2.resize(color_image, dsize=(depth_colormap_dim[1], depth_colormap_dim[0]), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        
        return(color_image, depth_colormap)

    def isOpened(self):
        ret, _, _ = self.rs.get_frame_stream()
        return(ret)


class ImgDepth():
    def __init__(self, cap):
        self.capture =  cap
        pass

    def read(self):
        color_frame, depth_colormap = self.capture.read()
        if depth_colormap is not  None:
            ret = True
        return(ret,depth_colormap)

    def isOpened(self):
        color_image, depth_colormap = self.capture.read()
        if color_image is not  None:
            ret = True
        return(ret)
        

class ImgColor():
    def __init__(self,cap):
        self.capture =  cap
        pass

    def read(self): 
        # capture = ImgCapture()
        color_image, depth_colormap = self.capture.read()
        if color_image is not  None:
            ret = True
        return(ret, color_image)

    def isOpened(self):
        # capture = ImgCapture()
        color_image, depth_colormap = self.capture.read()
        if color_image is not  None:
            ret = True
        return(ret)



def color():
    StreamProps = ps.StreamProps
    StreamProps.set_Page(StreamProps,HTML)
    address = ('10.112.33.161',9001) # Enter your IP address 
    try:
        StreamProps.set_Mode(StreamProps,'cv2')

        capture0 = ImgCapture()
        capture1 = ImgColor(capture0)

        StreamProps.set_Capture(StreamProps,capture1)
        StreamProps.set_Quality(StreamProps,90)
        server = ps.Streamer(address,StreamProps)
        print('Server started at','http://'+address[0]+':'+str(address[1]))
        server.serve_forever()
        print('done')
        
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pipeline.stop()
        server.socket.close()

def depth():
    StreamProps = ps.StreamProps
    StreamProps.set_Page(StreamProps,HTML)
    address = ('10.112.33.161',9000) # Enter your IP address 
    try:
        StreamProps.set_Mode(StreamProps,'cv2')

        capture0 = ImgCapture()
        capture2 = ImgDepth(capture0)

        StreamProps.set_Capture(StreamProps,capture2)
        StreamProps.set_Quality(StreamProps,90)
        server = ps.Streamer(address,StreamProps)
        print('Server started at','http://'+address[0]+':'+str(address[1]))
        server.serve_forever()
        
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pipeline.stop()
        server.socket.close()        
        
if __name__=='__main__':
    # Start streaming
    pipeline.start(config)

    t1 = threading.Thread(target=depth).start()

    t2 = threading.Thread(target=color).start()
```

Comment: I precise that to get the video flux :

http://10.112.33.161:9000/stream.mjpg 
or 
http://10.112.33.161:9001/stream.mjpg

(with your own adress of course)

Comment: Can you explain better your issue?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear.

What I want to do:
Stream to Web Browser my Color AND Depth video but each one in their own port. Because I want to access it with another application but also being able to see it.

To do this I wanted to use multithreading one thread to send Color Video and one thread for Depth video.

Comment: Finally found a way to make it works

Answer (score 0):

If someone need to stream Depth Camera from Intel:

```
import cv2
import pyrealsense2 as rs
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response




app = Flask('hello')

HTML="""
<html>
<head>
<title>PyShine Live Streaming</title>
</head>

<body>
<center><h1> PyShine Live Streaming Multiple videos </h1></center>
<center><img src="youradresse:port/stream.mjpg" width='360' height='240' autoplay playsinline></center>

</body>
</html>
"""



# Configure depth and color streams
pipeline = rs.pipeline()
config = rs.config()

# Get device product line for setting a supporting resolution
pipeline_wrapper = rs.pipeline_wrapper(pipeline)
pipeline_profile = config.resolve(pipeline_wrapper)
device = pipeline_profile.get_device()
device_product_line = str(device.get_info(rs.camera_info.product_line))

found_rgb = False
for s in device.sensors:
    if s.get_info(rs.camera_info.name) == 'RGB Camera':
        found_rgb = True
        break
if not found_rgb:
    print("The demo requires Depth camera with Color sensor")
    exit(0)

config.enable_stream(rs.stream.depth, 640, 480, rs.format.z16, 30)

if device_product_line == 'L500':
    config.enable_stream(rs.stream.color, 960, 540, rs.format.bgr8, 30)
else:
    config.enable_stream(rs.stream.color, 640, 480, rs.format.bgr8, 30)




class ImgCapture():

    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def read(self):
        # Wait for a coherent pair of frames: depth and color
        self.frames = pipeline.wait_for_frames()
        depth_frame = self.frames.get_depth_frame()
        color_frame = self.frames.get_color_frame()

        # Convert images to numpy arrays
        depth_image = np.asanyarray(depth_frame.get_data())
        color_image = np.asanyarray(color_frame.get_data())
        
        # Convert image of 16uint to 2x 8uint


        # Apply colormap on depth image (image must be converted to 8-bit per pixel first)
        depth_colormap = cv2.convertScaleAbs(depth_image, alpha=0.03)
        depth_colormap_dim = depth_colormap.shape
        color_colormap_dim = color_image.shape

        # If depth and color resolutions are different, resize color image to match depth image for display
        if depth_colormap_dim != color_colormap_dim:
            color_image = cv2.resize(color_image, dsize=(depth_colormap_dim[1], depth_colormap_dim[0]), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        
        return(color_image, depth_colormap)

    def isOpened(self):
        ret, _, _ = self.rs.get_frame_stream()
        return(ret)


class ImgDepth():
    def __init__(self, cap):
        self.capture =  cap
        pass

    def read(self):
        color_frame, depth_colormap = self.capture.read()
        if depth_colormap is not  None:
            ret = True
        return(ret,depth_colormap)

    def isOpened(self):
        color_image, depth_colormap = self.capture.read()
        if color_image is not  None:
            ret = True
        return(ret)
        

class ImgColor():
    def __init__(self,cap):
        self.capture =  cap
        pass

    def read(self): 
        # capture = ImgCapture()
        color_image, depth_colormap = self.capture.read()
        if color_image is not  None:
            ret = True
        return(ret, color_image)

    def isOpened(self):
        # capture = ImgCapture()
        color_image, depth_colormap = self.capture.read()
        if color_image is not  None:
            ret = True
        return(ret)




def gen_frames_depth():  
    while True:
        success, DEPTH = capture_depth.read()
        print(DEPTH)
        if not success:
            break
        else:
            _, buffer_DEPTH = cv2.imencode('.jpg', DEPTH)
            frame_depth = buffer_DEPTH.tobytes() 
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                    b'Content-Type:image/jpeg\r\n'
                    b'Content-Length: ' + f"{len(frame_depth)}".encode() + b'\r\n'
                    b'\r\n' + frame_depth + b'\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed_depth')
def video_feed_depth():
    return Response(gen_frames_depth(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--frame')



def gen_frames_color():  
    while True:
        success, RGB = capture_color.read()
        if not success:
            break
        else:
            _, buffer_RGB = cv2.imencode('.jpg', RGB)
            frame_RGB = buffer_RGB.tobytes() 
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                    b'Content-Type:image/jpeg\r\n'
                    b'Content-Length: ' + f"{len(frame_RGB)}".encode() + b'\r\n'
                    b'\r\n' + frame_RGB + b'\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed_color')
def video_feed_color():
    return Response(gen_frames_color(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--frame')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return """
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8  offset-lg-2">
            <h3 class="mt-5">Live Streaming</h3>
            <img src="/video_feed_depth" width="50%">
            <img src="/video_feed_color" width="50%">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>        
    """

if __name__=='__main__':
    # Start streaming
    pipeline.start(config)
    capture0 = ImgCapture()
    capture_depth = ImgDepth(capture0)
    capture_color = ImgColor(capture0)
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```